# Trigger syntax error

Tags: mysql, triggers

My first time using triggers. Can anyone please explain why this trigger won't work? The error I'm getting is inconclusive (error near '' at line 5)

```
create trigger queue after update on downloads
for each row
begin
    if NEW.completed = 1 then
        insert into s_queue ( website_id ) values ( NEW.website_id );
    end if;
end;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the delimiter from `;` to something else, before defining any stored procedure/functions or triggers.

```
delimiter ||
create trigger queue after update on downloads
for each row
begin
    if NEW.completed = 1 then
        insert into s_queue ( website_id ) values ( NEW.website_id );
    end if;
end||

delimiter;
```